# Arrange columns as size in bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am dynamically printing bootstrap columns divs as follows using angular2

```
[col-md-6][col-md-12][col-md-6][col-md-12][col-md-6][col-md-12][col-md-6][col-md-12]
```

but the actual grid is appearing as

```
[col-md-6]
[col-md-12]
[col-md-6]
[col-md-12]
[col-md-6]
[col-md-12]
[col-md-6]
[col-md-12]
```

I want to arrange columns like

```
[col-md-6][col-md-6]
[col-md-12]
[col-md-12]
[col-md-6][col-md-6]
[col-md-12]
[col-md-12]
```

Here is the code

```
            <div class="row">
                <span *ngFor="let serviceItem of dashboardServicesList">
                    <div class="col-md-6 {{serviceItem.service}}-service">
                        <div class="service">
                            <a *ngIf="serviceItem.categoryHashmap" (click)="showSegments($event,serviceItem.service)">
                                <span class="service-title">{{serviceItem.displayName}}</span>
                                <i class="fa {{serviceItem.chevron}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="serviceItem.categoryHashmap" class="col-md-12 segments {{serviceItem.is_active}} {{serviceItem.service}}">
                        <ul class="segments-boxes">
                            <li *ngFor="let item of serviceItem.serviceSegments">
                                <a target="_blank" href="{{item.url}}">{{item.displayName}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </span>
             </div>
```

How to arrange this ? thank you.

Comment: well. why not print them in the order you want them ? if you don't share a working example of your problem ( snippet )  we cannot do much to help

Comment: Do you wrap each in a row perhaps? ... As pointed out, we need to see the code you use

Comment: It's dynamic, look in col-md-6 i am showing main service and in col-md-12 showing sub-services, I have to show sub-services in col-md-12 of each service.

Comment: You can't just add those columns in a single row, they need one row per 12 items, as in row - col6 - col6 - row, row - col12 - row, and so on

Comment: Also, if you can't do that, you need to make the outer row a flex container, and set 6 and 12 col. items to 50% resp. 100% flex-basis

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is happening is because of the sequence you're using.

```
col-md-6 + col-md-12 = col-md-18
```

This won't fit on one `row` and thats why it isn't working.

Fix your sequence and add `row`'s to it, output as example below:

```
[row][col-md-6][col-md-6][row][row][col-md-12][row][row][col-md-12][row][row][col-md-6][col-md-6][row][row][col-md-12][row]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Each group need both start and end row tag...updated it myself, and upvoted

Comment: @Deathstorm, Ofcourse I know the col-md-6 and col-md-12 can not fit into a row. And you will understand from my code that it's not easy to change the sequence and wrap them into in row.